# FBLogOut: ios how to override calling UIActionSheet While FBLogOut in FBSDKLoginButtion

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, ios7, xcode6, logout

i am using FBSDK for login with FB. When the logout button is pressed it is calling `UIActionSheet`. How can I bypass the call to `UIActionSheet` or logout without calling `UIActionSheet`? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: for Logging Out call where ever you want                     let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
                    login.logOut()

Answer (score 0):

in swift -- Call this in button Action for making LogOut:

let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
  login.logOut()